# Flutter Android приложение не поддерживает уведомления в Webview

Tags: android, webview, flutter

Есть небольшое android приложение на flutter. Внутри встроен webview (плагин: flutter_webview_plugin, использует нативный webview), который открывает наш сайт. Сайт периодически будет присылать уведомления пользователю. Нужно, чтобы они приходили от этого приложения. В dart коде с помощью плагина: permission_handler 5.0.1+1 я проверил предоставлено ли разрешение на получение уведомлений - да, предоставлено:

```
print("Permission is granted: ${await Permission.notification.isGranted}");
```

Ответ logcat:

```
I/flutter (26996): Permission is granted: true
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при получении уведомления появляется сообщение: "Ваш браузер не поддерживает уведомления". Можно ли получать уведомления от сайтов, если они открыты через webview внутри flutter приложения? И если да, то как я могу решить эту проблему? С flutter я знаком очень плохо, поэтому мог что-то упустить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам и натив не даст такое сделать... Так как WebView использует специальный компонент в системе ([Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=ru)), который не знает что такое push notifications.

Есть несколько решений вашей проблемы:

1. Использовать API сайта.
2. Использовать [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging).
3. Парсить сайт и искать уведомления (плохая идея).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, решили выбрать Firebase Cloud Messaging.